# Excel: How to combine (almost) duplicate observations with different information?

Tags: excel, variables, join, binary, duplicates

I have a large data set in Excel that I've created a small example of below (Ex. 1). Name is a unique identifier and each person uses one or more types of transportation. I would like to have only one row per person and need to create binary variables for the different types of transport. I'm able to create the new variables (Ex. 2), but then do not know how to then combine the observations into just one row per person that contains the relevant information across observations (Ex. 3). If anyone can advise on how to get from Ex. 2 to Ex. 3, I would be so appreciative. Thanks in advance!

Example 1:

| NAME | TRANSPORT |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | Car |
| Jane | Bus |
| Mark | Car |
| Dave | Train |
| Dave | Bus |

Example 2:

| NAME | CAR | BUS | TRAIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Jane | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Mark | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Dave | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Dave | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Example 3:

| NAME | CAR | BUS | TRAIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Mark | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Dave | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: This is a simple Pivot table type operation. You can do this with the "regular" Insert/Pivot Table; or, for a bit more flexibility, you can use Power Query to pivot the data.

Answer (score 0):

(Ex. 1) TO (Ex. 3), Pivot table . (COLUMN A = NAME)
[image]